# how to group by the id to make all datasets to be one dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

currently, I have 50 dataset from same path('\home\data'), each dataset example like below:

dataset1.csv

| sentence | platform | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hello, I am good. | CNN | 001 |
| hello, how are u. | CNN | 001 |
| hello, xxxxxxxxx. | CNN | 001 |

dataset2.csv

| sentence | platform | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ok, xxxxxx. | FOX | 002 |
| ok, xxxxxx. | FOX | 002 |
| ok, xxxxxxxxx. | FOX | 002 |

dataset3.csv

| sentence | platform | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| well, xxxxxx. | MMM | 003 |
| well, xxxxxx. | MMM | 003 |
| well, xxxxxxxxx. | MMM | 003 |

I want to **combine all sentence** first, and **group by the id** and **make them to be one dataset** look like:

| content | platform | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hello, I am good.\n hello, how are u.\nhello, xxxxxxxxx. | CNN | 001 |
| ok, xxxxxx.ok, xxxxxx.ok, xxxxxx. | FOX | 002 |
| well, xxxxxxxxx.well, xxxxxxxxx.well, xxxxxxxxx. | MMM | 003 |

Will be very grateful if anyone can give me some idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired output by first concatenating the dataframes together, then using `groupby` to join the sentences together (grouped by platform and id).

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['hello, I am good.', 'hello, how are u.', 'hello, xxxxxxxx.'],
                    'platform': ['CNN', 'CNN', 'CNN'],
                    'id': ['001', '001', '001']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['ok, xxxxxxxx.', 'ok, xxxxxxxx.', 'ok, xxxxxxxxxx.'],
                    'platform': ['FOX', 'FOX', 'FOX'],
                    'id': ['002', '002', '002']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['well, xxxxxxxx.', 'well, xxxxxxxx.', 'well, xxxxxxxxxx.'],
                    'platform': ['MMM', 'MMM', 'MMM'],
                    'id': ['003', '003', '003']})

df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

df5 = df4.groupby(['platform', 'id'])['sentence'].apply('\n'.join).reset_index()

# reorder and rename the columns
df5 = df5[['sentence', 'platform', 'id']]
df5.columns = ['content', 'platform', 'id']
print(df5)
```

Output:

```
                                             content platform   id
0  hello, I am good.\nhello, how are u.\nhello, x...      CNN  001
1      ok, xxxxxxxx.\nok, xxxxxxxx.\nok, xxxxxxxxxx.      FOX  002
2  well, xxxxxxxx.\nwell, xxxxxxxx.\nwell, xxxxxx...      MMM  003
```

You could also reverse the order and use `groupby` on each individual dataframe, then concatenate the results together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to read all the files and `pandas.concat` to concatenate them after transformation:

```
from glob import glob
df = pd.concat([(pd.read_csv(filename)
                   .groupby('id', as_index=False)
                   .agg({'sentence': '\n'.join,
                         'platform': 'first', 
                         'id': 'first'})
                )
                for filename in glob('dataset*.csv')
                ])
```